# Changing the format from a mySQL datetime format to a different type in ruby?

Tags: ruby, datetime

I am attempting to change an SQL datetime variable (`2016-06-09 14:29:34`) into a format that looks like this (`00:00_20160601`). I have tried to follow a couple of SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090451/format-the-date-using-ruby-on-rails) that will allow me to format a Time object.

This is what I have done so far:

```
start_datetime = "2016-06-09 14:29:34"
t =Time.new(start_datetime)
t.strftime("%H:%M_%Y%d%m")
```

This results in the time being formatted to `2016-01-01 00:00:00 +0000`, which is obviously not what I want. I was wondering if someone could help me format the datetime object the way I specified?

Comment: Where is the time being formatted as `2016-01-01 00:00:00 +0000`? That `strftime` call should produce the format you're after.

Comment: Why is your day value changing from `09` in the input to `01` in the output?

Comment: The code in the question produces the desired answer when run in Ruby 2.3.1 on Linux.  I'll take you at your word that the actual output is what you say it is, but that's very strange indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `DateTime`:

```
require 'datetime'

DateTime.parse("2016-06-09 14:29:34").strftime("%H:%M_%Y%d%m")
#=> "14:29_20160906"
```

The format you're feeding in is basically ISO-8601 so it's parsed by default.

Feeding that value into [`Time.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-c-new) is completely incorrect. The first argument there is the year, the rest have to be supplied separately. That's why you get `2016-01-01`, since everything else comes out as defaults.

`Time.new` is converting automatically and the result of `"2016-06-09 14:29:34".to_i` is `2016`.

Comment: [Be careful with `parse`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15791667/128421). It assumes non-US-based date formats and can break code either returning a swapped month/day or by raising an exception. It's also slower because it has to try matching all its possible formats. If the incoming string is from a database, and hasn't already been converted to a DateTime or Time, I'll use `strptime` for speed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear why your day value changes from `09` in the input to `01` in the desired output, so I'll use the normal thing and output the same as was input:

```
require 'time'

start_datetime = "2016-06-09 14:29:34"
t = Time.strptime(start_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
t.strftime('00:00_%Y%m%d') # => "00:00_20160609"
```

Since the hours and minutes are being thrown away there are a couple of other ways to go about this.

Ignore the hours and minutes when parsing:

```
t = Time.strptime(start_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Or use a Date object instead of a Time object:

```
require 'date'

start_datetime = "2016-06-09 14:29:34"
t = Date.strptime(start_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')
t.strftime('00:00_%Y%m%d') # => "00:00_20160609"
```